# Blazor select-like component does not update value in data source

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor, client-side

In my Blazor Webassembly (client-side) 3.2.0 application, I have a lot of the following `select` elements on a page, which create a combo box listing available items of an `enum`:

```cs
<select @bind="SomeEnumValue">
    @foreach (var element in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)))
    {
        <option value="@element">@element</option>
    }
</select>
```

While this works, I want to prevent repeating myself over and over for every such combo box, and thought of creating the following `EnumSelect` component:

```html
@typeparam T
<select @bind="Value">
    @foreach (var element in Enum.GetValues(typeof(@T)))
    {
        <option value="@element">@element</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public T Value { get; set; } = default(T)!;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<T> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```html
<EnumSelect T="SomeEnum" @bind-Value="SomeEnumValue" />
```

However, while the display of the `SomeEnumValue` property and enum items works, the property is not written back to upon selecting another item from the combo box.

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I kinda suspect the `EnumSelect` component storing its own copy of that value, not writing it back, but I thought the binding solves this for me.

Is there any (easier) way to get this combo box component working? Where is my mistake (in understanding bindings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer by rewording my question a bit (sorry, not yet used to all the Blazor terminology): [Blazor TwoWay Binding on custom Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196797/blazor-twoway-binding-on-custom-component)

In case of my problem, the final working component looks like this: The check if the value actually changed inside the property was required, or I hung my app (possibly because it wanted to set it over and over again?):

```html
@typeparam T
<select @bind="Value">
    @foreach (var element in Enum.GetValues(typeof(@T)))
    {
        <option value="@element">@element</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    private T _value = default(T)!;

    [Parameter]
    public T Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value.Equals(value))
                return;

            _value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<T> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```